# Limit proof of derivative function

Tags: derivatives

$f:[0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice differentiable. If $f''$is limited and there is $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)$, show that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: When you say $f''$ is limited do you mean that it is bounded?

Comment: yes, $f''$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that for all $A>0$ the set $T_A=\{x : |f'(x)|>A\}$ is bounded.

By contradiction: Suppose that for some $A>0,$ the set $S_A=\{x :f'(x)>A\}$ has no upper bound.(The case where $U_A=\{x:f(x)<-A\}$ is unbounded, is handled similarly.)

For $x_1\in S_A,$ there must exist $y>x$ such that $f'(y)\leq A/2,$ otherwise for $x>x_1$ we have $f(x)=f(x_1)+\int_{x_1}^x f'(u) du>(x-x_1)A/2$ which tends to $\infty$ as $x\to \infty.$
 So for $x_1\in S_A$ let $$x_2=\inf \{x>x_1:f'(x)=A/2\}$$ which exists from the previous sentence and because $f'$ is continuous (because $f''$ exists).
 Now let $K=\sup_{x\geq 0} |f''(x)|.$ By the mean value theorem we have ,for $x_1\in S_A,$ some $x_3\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $$(f'(x_2)-f'(x_1))/(x_2-x_1)=f''(x_3).$$ $$\text {But } |f(x_2)-f(x_1)>|A/2-A|=A/2.$$ So we have $$0<A/2<|f'(x_2)-f'(x_1)|=(x_2-x_1)|f''(x_3)|\leq (x_2-x_1)K.$$ 
This gives $0<A/2 K<x_2-x_1.$

Note that this implies $K>0.$

From the def'n of $x_2$ we have $u\in [x_1,x_2]\implies f'(u)\geq A/2.$ 
Therefore $$ f(x_2)-f(x_1)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f'(u) du \geq \int_{x_1}^{x_2}(A/2) du=(x_2-x_1)A/2>(A/2 K)A/2=A^2K/4.$$ If $S_A$ is unbounded then $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sup_{y>x}|f(y)-f(x)|>A^2K/4>0,$ contradicting the existence of $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x).$ Similarly we get a contradiction if $U_A=\{x :f'(x)<-A\}$ is unbounded for some $A>0.$